# Looping through Array, return largest number

Tags: arrays, sorting

For the Life of me i can not understand why this doesn't work.
I'm trying to find the Largest number in the array. Plz explain what I did wrong here.

```
     function largestOfFour(arr) {
     var maxArry = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var Max = 0;
     for (let y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
        var currentElement = arr[i][y];
        if (currentElement >= Max) {
            Max = currentElement;
        }
    }
    console.log(Max);
    }
    }

    largestOfFour([
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
    [9, 4, 5, 64, 3],
    [4, 4, 6, 8, 35],
    [3, 5, 76, 54, 3]
    ]);
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Have you tried to debug your programs?

Comment: (don't `console.log` in functions, it's a bad practice)

Comment: [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). "If your program produces different results to what you expected, have you stated what you expected, why you expected it, and the actual results?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var largestNr = 0;
  arr.map(child => {
    var largestChild = Math.max(...child)
    if (largestChild > largestNr) largestNr = largestChild
  })
  return largestNr;
}
```

or if you care about IE browser support of Spread opearator, use:

```
var largestChild = Math.max.apply(null, child)
```

Array.Map() is more reliable these days because it's easier to use and less bug-prone :)

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: (`Math.max` takes less bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sort array:

```
var Arr = [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 9];

for (var i = 1; i < Arr.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (Arr[i] > Arr[j]) {
          var x = Arr[i];
          Arr[i] = Arr[j];
          Arr[j] = x;
        }

console.log(Arr);
```

then get four first item in array.

Comment: @Wiil please test this

Answer (score 0):

Your variable assignment of `Max` needs to go outside your `for` loop as every time you finish your inner loop, `Max` will reset to 0 as you iterate through the outer loop.